# Updating properties after a callback in react

Tags: reactjs, typescript, properties, callback

I have the following code within Typescript React:

I am trying to set loggingIn = "true" when I get the call back from the component.  This would allow the component to show an indicator that its logging in.

What is the best way to approach this?

Thank you in advance,
Marty

Login.tsx

```
import * as React from "react";
import * as ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import { LoginPanel } from "../Shared/LoginPanel.tsx";


    let loggingIn: string =  "false";

    ReactDOM.render(
        <LoginPanel loggingIn={ loggingIn } onLogin={ 
            function (email:string, password:string) {
                this.loggingIn = "true";
                alert("Logging in with e-mail" + email + " and password " + password);
            }.bind(this)
        } />,
        document.getElementById("loginpanel")
    )
```

LoginPanel.tsx

```
import * as React from "react";

export interface Properties { loggingIn:string; onLogin: (email: string, password: string) => void; }

export class LoginPanel extends React.Component<Properties, {}> {

    email: HTMLInputElement = null;
    password: HTMLInputElement = null;



    submit = (e: any) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.props.onLogin(this.email.value,this.password.value);
    };



    render() {

        return <div className="row">
            <div className="col-xs-3">


                <h3>Log in with your email account</h3>
                <form onSubmit={this.submit}>
                    <div className="form-group">

                        { this.props.loggingIn }

                        <label htmlFor="email" className="sr-only">Email</label>
                        <input type="email" ref={(input) => { this.email = input; } } className="form-control" placeholder="somebody@example.com" />
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <label htmlFor="key" className="sr-only">Password</label>
                        <input type="password" ref={(input) => { this.password = input; } }  className="form-control" placeholder="Password" />
                    </div>

                    <input type="submit" id="btn-login" className="btn btn-custom btn-lg btn-block" value="Log in" />
                </form>
                <a href="javascript:;" className="forget" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".forget-modal">Forgot your password?</a>
                <hr />
            </div>
        </div>
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure the way to do it in typescript.... but you would assign `loggingIn` to the Login state and then update in the `onLogin` method with `this.setState({loggingIn: true})`.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Login.tsx` should look like this:

```
let loggingIn: string =  "false";
function onLogin(email: string, password: string) {
    loggingIn = "true";
    console.log(`logged in. email: ${ email }, password: ${ password }`);
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <LoginPanel loggingIn={ loggingIn } onLogin={ onLogin } />, document.getElementById("loginpanel")
)
```

And the `LoginPanel.tsx`:

```
export interface Properties {
    loggingIn: string;
    onLogin: (email: string, password: string) => void;
}
interface State {
    loggingIn: string;
}

export class LoginPanel extends React.Component<Properties, State> {
    email: HTMLInputElement = null;
    password: HTMLInputElement = null;

    constructor(props: Properties) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            loggingIn: props.loggingIn
        };
    }

    submit = (e: React.FormEvent) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.props.onLogin(this.email.value, this.password.value);
    };

    render() {
        return <div className="row">
            <div className="col-xs-3">
                <h3>Log in with your email account</h3>
                <form onSubmit={ this.submit }>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        { this.state.loggingIn }
                        <label htmlFor="email" className="sr-only">Email</label>
                        <input type="email" ref={(input) => { this.email = input; } } className="form-control" placeholder="somebody@example.com" />
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <label htmlFor="key" className="sr-only">Password</label>
                        <input type="password" ref={(input) => { this.password = input; } }  className="form-control" placeholder="Password" />
                    </div>

                    <input type="submit" id="btn-login" className="btn btn-custom btn-lg btn-block" value="Log in" />
                </form>
                <a href="javascript:;" className="forget" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".forget-modal">Forgot your password?</a>
                <hr />
            </div>
        </div>
    }
}
```

Comment: Everything is working except the update.

It feels like I have to trigger the LoginPanel.tsx to update, setting the value outside of the component doesn't feel right.